# Google Chrome & FB Like Button at the bottom of the page

Tags: google-chrome, resize, facebook-like, developer-tools, css

I'm encountering a strange issue.
I have a facebook button at the bottom of a page. When clicked, the facebook "Comment/share" box pops up.
The behaviour is correct under FF and IE, but not in Chrome, where the box is cut by the bottom of the page. In other words, the page isn't resized as it is under FF and IE.
The page has a min-height and max-height, and the containers have an overflow:visible attribute as the facebook docs advises to avoid some display issues of the share iframe.
The curious thing is that the bug disappears by simply opening the developer tools, and checking/unchecking any CSS attributes of any parent element of the FB-button.

My guess is that the resize of the window isn't captured by Chrome when the button is clicked, but it is when using the developer tools.
I tried to explore other sources of the problem (max-height not working properly or a higher element having a overflow:hidden) but I found nothing conclusive.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an issue if you're running a theme in Chrome. If you are, try resetting to the default theme:

```
options > personal stuff > themes > reset to default theme
```

Also, make sure you aren't zoomed out or in. Chrome gets a little funky with the zooming.

Assuming those aren't the issues, try putting the Share code in a div with a unique ID or class:

```
 <div id="myFacebookContainer">Plugin HTML Here</div>
```

Your CSS would include something along the lines of this:

```
#myFacebookContainer span{
  height:25px;
}
#myFacebookContainer iframe{
  height:25px;
}
```

I hope one of those suggestions helps!

Comment: Thank you, this helped my much.
Nevertheless, the whole page is now higher, of the height specified in the CSS, even if the share box is not shown, and this under all browsers. But it will now be easier for me to find the right fix !